# Not getting slider images after reloading the html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

[This is the screenshot of my html page. this commented area is my issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sr2fU.jpg)

Comment: Please include the relevant information in teh question and not only as a link!

Comment: I see several errors in your console. Fix them.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem starts with a couple of error's :)

Your Javascript crashes because it looks for a function that doesn't exist "$(...).fancybox()". This means that either you didn't include the fancybox library or that the file where you call in the function fancybox is loaded before the fancybox library is loaded in.

Next problem is that the images that are used in your slider (I assume). Do no longer exist. Try clicking them in the console to see if you can access them in the browser.

Last but not least. You tagged your question as "java". Javascript and java are not the same thing. Your problem involves javascript. Might want to change that tag next time so you can get anwsered faster.

I Hope this helped a bit :)

Good luck!